# What is the purpose of hiding a device in Device Manager (Windows)

Tags: windows, driver, device

During driver development for Windows, the devnode status bit DN_NO_SHOW_IN_DM can be used to hide the device in Device Manager and some device setup classes are also hidden.

What is the purpose of hiding these devices and what use cases benefit from it?